# TypeError at /create Listing() got unexpected keyword arguments: 'description'

Tags: python, html, django, cs50

Im trying to make an ecommerce site but it wont allow me to create the listing and post it
heres views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import User, Category, Listing

def index(request):
    activeListings = Listing.objects.filter(isActive=True)
    allCategories = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, "auctions/index.html",{
        "listings": activeListings,
        "categories": allCategories
    })

def displayCategory(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        categoryFromForm = request.POST['category']
        category = category.objects.get(categoryName=categoryFromForm)
        activeListings = Listing.objects.filter(isActive=True, category=category)
        allCategories = Category.objects.all()
        return render(request, "auctions/index.html",{
            "listings": activeListings,
            "categories": allCategories
        })


def createListing(request):
    if request.method=="GET":
        allCategories = Category.objects.all()
        return render(request, "auctions/create.html", {
            "categories": allCategories
        })
    else:
        title = request.POST.get("title")
        description = request.POST.get("description")
        imageurl = request.POST.get("imageurl")
        price = request.POST.get("price")
        category = request.POST.get("category")
        currentUser = request.user
        categoryData=Category.objects.get(categoryName=category)
        newListing = Listing(
            title = title,
            description = description,
            imageUrl = imageurl,
            price = str(price),
            category = categoryData,
            owner = currentUser
        )
        newListing.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(index)

def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Attempt to sign user in
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        # Check if authentication successful
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/login.html", {
                "message": "Invalid username and/or password."
            })
    else:
        return render(request, "auctions/login.html")


def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))


def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        email = request.POST["email"]

        # Ensure password matches confirmation
        password = request.POST["password"]
        confirmation = request.POST["confirmation"]
        if password != confirmation:
            return render(request, "auctions/register.html", {
                "message": "Passwords must match."
            })

        # Attempt to create new user
        try:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
            user.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            return render(request, "auctions/register.html", {
                "message": "Username already taken."
            })
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    else:
        return render(request, "auctions/register.html")
```

heres models.py

```
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Category(models.Model):
    categoryName = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.categoryName

class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    imageUrl = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    price = models.FloatField(max_length=1000)
    isActive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="user")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="category")

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

heres index.html

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>Active Listings</h2>
    <form action="{% url 'displayCategory' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="category">Choose a category:</label>
        <select name="category" id="category">
            {% for cat in categories %}
                <option value="{{ cat }}">{{ cat }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Select</button>
    </form>

    <div class="row mx-3">
        {% for listing in listings %}
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ listing.imageUrl }}" alt="{{ listing.title }}">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{ listing.title }}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">{{ listing.description }}</p>
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

here's create.html

```html
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>Create Listing</h2>
    <form action="{% url 'create' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Enter Title:">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Description">Description</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Enter description:">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="imageurl">Image</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="imageurl" placeholder="Enter image url:">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="price">Price</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="Enter Price">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="category">Choose a category:</label>
            <select name="category" id="category">
                {% for cat in categories %}
                    <option value="{{ cat }}">{{ cat }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add listing</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

i dont know what to do but here was the problem

```
title = request.POST.get("title")
        description = request.POST.get("description")
        imageurl = request.POST.get("imageurl")
        price = request.POST.get("price")
        category = request.POST.get("category")
        currentUser = request.user
        categoryData=Category.objects.get(categoryName=category)
        newListing = Listing(
                          …
            title = title,
            description = description,
            imageUrl = imageurl,
            price = str(price),
            category = categoryData,
            owner = currentUser
```

i dont know whats going on please help its for a cs50W project called commerce if any of you have done it.

Comment: Your `Listing` model has no `description` field...

Answer (score 1):

Your `Listing` model has no `description` field. If you really want to create a listing with description, then add a description field to your `Listing` model and migrate the changes.

If you don't need description, remove it from your views.py `createListing` method.